# UIPicker - how record the standard selectedRow if user only click the OK button

Tags: xcode, uipickerview, swift4

I have a UIpicker in modal window. Everything works fine, except one thing. When the user click the input text field, the modal window with the UIpickerView opens as expected. If the selected row is the correct one and the user click the OK button, then the current code is not able to registrer the value.

```
// Set the default row, so if user click ok without changing it is recorded
self.picker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
```

Is there an alternative to didSelectRow? I assume that is the issue, as they user don't select a row as it is already preselected by the code.

```
// Capture the picker selection
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    // This method is triggered whenever the user makes a change to the picker selection.
    // The parameter named row and component represents what was selected.
    selectedType = pickerData[row] as String
}
```

Comment: Sometimes even the most obvious is difficult to see....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well solved it. just add a test to see if the selectedType was nil.

```
@IBAction func OkBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        // update text to selected value
        if selectedType == nil {
            typeTextField.text = pickerData[defaultRow]
        } else {
             typeTextField.text = selectedType
        }
        animateOut()
    }
```